# Awk based filtering of data on a file in Linux

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file data which are trying to filter via awk, i am able to filter the data but want the awk statement to be simpler into one line:

### File contents:

```
Entity Name
Value
Unknown dbs636294051.klm.bet.com: /opt
N/A
Unknown dbs636294051.klm.bet.com: /tmp
N/A
Unknown dbs636294051.klm.bet.com: /var
N/A
```

### My trial:

```
awk  '!/^N/{ if($2 ~ /klm/) print $2}' file | awk -F":" '{print $1}'
```

The above works but i'm looking if this can be trimmed to the before pipe line:

```
dbs636294051.klm.bet.com
dbs636294051.klm.bet.com
dbs636294051.klm.bet.com
```

Comment: What does `Unknown` represent in your input? Is it literally the word `Unknown` or could it be any random text where you just don't know what it might be or something else?

Comment: @EdMorton, the `Unknown` is a starting line for all of the Key missing Values and that's can be considered main leading string here. In another words its main String in a file that starts with `Unknown`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a single awk command, setting the field separator to 1 or more spaces or `:`, check if field 1 does not start with `N` ad that it does contain `klm`

To be really specific, you could also write `^N\/A$`

Thanks to the comments of @[Renaud Pacalet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1773798/renaud-pacalet) and @[Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) the command can look like:

```
awk -F'[[:blank:]]+|:' '!/^N/ && $2 ~ /klm/{print $2}' file
```

In parts

```
awk -F'[[:blank:]]+|:' '   # Set the field separator to either 1+ spaces or tabs or a semicolon
!/^N/ && $2 ~ /klm/        # If the record does not start with `N` and field 2 does contain klm
{print $2}                 # Print the second column
```

Output

```
dbs636294051.klm.bet.com
dbs636294051.klm.bet.com
dbs636294051.klm.bet.com
```

Comment: Nice. `-F'[[:space:]]+|:'` may be safer.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Thanks, that is much better indeed, as there may be more spaces between the fields.

Comment: Note that it is not `$2` that must not start with `N`, it's the full record.

Comment: Or `awk -F'[[:blank:]]+|:' '!/^N/ && $2 ~ /klm/{print $2}'  file`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, you are right about that `!` :-) Because this part `!/^N/` by default matches at the start of the string correct?

Comment: @Thefourthbird The `!/^N/` checks against `$0`, the whole record, yes, at the start.

Comment: Its really been tough to choose a single answer but i have to do it for posterity hence i see most bet is empowered on the @Thefourthbird answer so i'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am still learning as we go about this awesome tool.

Comment: Dear @Thefourthbird .. thanks for the answer and improvements on the fly, much appreciated.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, you are among one of the inspiration for these tricky one lines, thnx again for throwing ideas here.

Comment: @kulfi You are welcome, I also learned some new insights from Wiktor Stribiżew and Renaud Pacalet as I do on a daily basis here on SO :-)

Answer (score 3):

The `sub` function can be used to trim the colon and anything following it from `$2`:

```
awk '!/^N/ && $2 ~ /klm/ {sub(/:.*$/,"",$2); print $2}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a quick and dirty one, which works for the given example.
If you have more filter rules, it's also easy to adjust.

```
awk -F'[:\\s]' 'NR>1 && $2~/klm/{print $2}' f
636294051.klm.bet.com
636294051.klm.bet.com
636294051.klm.bet.com
```

### Update, another approach:

```
awk '$2~/klm/ && (($0=$2)+sub(/:.*/,""))' f
```

Comment: `\s` is gawk specific and doesn't work as `[:space:]` within brackets.

Comment: `/klm/` match anywhere, not just in field `$2`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet yes, it should be `$2~/klm/'

Comment: @rowboat, you're right. how about the 2nd approach in my answer. ;-)

Comment: Dear @Kent, thanks a lot for nice answer and on the fly improvement as well, you are one of gem guy!

Comment: @kulfi your're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

awk '/Unknown/{gsub(/:/,"",$0);print $2}' file

Comment: Dear @Alejandro, and excellent approach, this also work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you have two piped `awk` commands with different field separators like

```
awk  '!/^N/{ if($2 ~ /klm/) print $2}' file | awk -F":" '{print $1}'
```

you might use [`split`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function to turn that into single `awk` commands, in this case

```
awk  '!/^N/{ if($2 ~ /klm/){split($2,arr,":");print arr[1]}}' file
```

Disclaimer: this answer pertains solely for changing 2 `awk`s into single, other ways to ameliorate are outside scope of this answer.